# Removing Duplicates from table in SQL with no primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a table, for example:

```
Country State   City    Rate1   Rate2   Rate3
US      CA     Irvine   1       13      22
US      CA     Irvine   0       0       0
US      WA     Seattle  1       231     22
US      WA     Seattle  0       0       0
```

I'm trying to remove the duplicate records where all rate columns=0

So I'd like to remove the following rows:

```
Country State   City    Rate1   Rate2   Rate3
US      CA     Irvine   0        0      0
US      WA     Seattle  0        0      0
```

variations of the query below:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT myTable.*
, RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY patientID ORDER BY ID)
FROM myTable 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: please explain your problem!

Comment: If you want to remove all rows having all rows 0 then why don't you do: `delete from myTable where Rate1=0 and Rate2=0 and Rate3=0`? Or do you want to keep one and delete rest? In that case which one to keep? Please clarify your requirement.

Comment: Why do you not have a primary key? Do you at least have a clustered index?

Comment: Why people posting similar answer, when already an answer is posted!

Comment: I don't want to delete all rows where rates are 0. I only want to delete all rows where rates are 0 that also have a record with valid rates. As we can also have records where rates are 0, with no duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... so something like:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
    myTable.*,
    RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Country, State, City ORDER BY Rate1 DESC)
FROM myTable 
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN <> 1
```

Dunno what you want to order by... How do you decide which of the duplicates to remove? 
In this example it will remove everything with the lower Rate1 than the max

Comment: This isn't giving me the results I wanted. I need some additional logic to select the records where rates are 0. When I ran this query, I have rows numbers=1 with rates as zero and then RN=2 with valid rate values. I want to keep the records which are duplicate by country, state, city, and have rate values.

Answer (score 0):

try like below , using count window function make sure value is duplicate

```
   WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT *,
        count()OVER(PARTITION BY Country, State, City ) as cnt    
        FROM myTable 
    ) delete from cte where cnt>1 and rate1=0 and rate2=0 and rate3=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
    myTable.*,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Country, State, City ORDER BY Rate1 DESC) AS RN
FROM myTable 
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
AND Rate1 =0 AND  Rate2 =0 AND  Rate3 =0 --since you mentioned only duplicates where all rates are 0 need to be removed
```

Comment: This isn't quite working. Entries with valid rates are getting tagged to row number 2, and entries with rates=0 are getting tagged to RN=1. So I wouldn't be able to identify the duplicate country/state/city without a rate.